# Is there a nontrivial fiber or principal bundle over $S^3$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Is  there  a  nontrivial fiber or principal bundle over $S^3$?I know that, by  a paper of Steenrod,see the link below,   every sphere bundle on 3- sphere is trivial but what about arbitrary fiber bundle?

[Triviality/non-triviality of line/circle bundle over $S^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269745/triviality-non-triviality-of-line-circle-bundle-over-s3)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Isomorphism classes of principal $G$-bundles over $S^3$ are classified by $\pi_3(BG)\cong \pi_2(G)$. So there is a nontrivial principal $G$-bundle over $S^3$ if and only if $G$ has non-vanishing second homotopy group.

As all Lie groups have vanishing second homotopy group $G$, any fiber bundle over $S^3$ with structure group a Lie group is trivial, in particular $S^3$ has no nontrivial vector bundles over it.

To get a nontrivial example, pick your favorite topological group $G$ with $\pi_2(G)\neq 0$ and a nontrivial element in that group. Pulling back the universal $G$-bundle gives you a principal $G$-bundle over $S^3$ which is nontrivial.

A good source of examples are diffeomorphism groups $Diff(M)$ of closed manifolds $M$, which are not finite dimensional manifolds (in particular Lie groups) in general, so may have nonvanishing second homotopy group. By the above argument $\pi_2(Diff(M))$ classifies principal $Diff(M)$-bundles and hence (via the associated bundle construction) also fiber bundles with fiber $M$ and structure group $Diff(M)$, i.e. smooth $M$-bundles over $S^3$.

As an example, [Hatcher](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/newDiffS1xS2.pdf) calculated the homotopy type of $Diff(S^1\times S^2)$: It is the one of $O(2)\times O(3)\times \Omega SO(3)$, so we arrive at $$\pi_2(O(2)\times O(3)\times \Omega SO(3))=\pi_2(\Omega SO(3))\cong\pi_3(SO(3))\cong\pi_3(S^3)\cong\mathbb Z.$$ Hence, smooth $S^1\times S^2$-bundles over $S^3$ are classified by the integers.

Comment: +1 for a cool answer with great facts and examples!  Couldn't we also use the clutching construction to say directly that the $ F $ bundles over $ S^3 $ are classified by $ \pi_2(F) $. So taking $ F=S^2 $  (or $ F=S^2 \times S^1 $ for your example) the smooth $ S^2 $ (or $ S^1 \times S^2 $) bundles are classified by integers $ \pi_{3-1}(F) \cong \pi_2(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z} $?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira I do not think that will do! Clutching works for the associated principal bundle, which in the above example is a $\rm{Diff}(S^1 \times S^2)$ bundle. Hence, you do need the Hatcher's result to conclude the classification.